# Facebook like button is not getting displayed at all when placed it in an IFrame

Tags: facebook-like, cross-domain

Facebook like button is not getting displayed at all when placed it in an IFrame. Also the iframe is loading a page from different domain. So basically it is a cross domain scenario. I have the channel file on the iframe domain setup properly.

Comment: I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you load the page from the iframe normally in another tab/window, do you see the like buttons normally?